# How can I create a VM instance with GPUs on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: gpu, google-cloud-platform

How can I create a VM instance with GPUs on Google Cloud Platform?

When I go to https://console.cloud.google.com/compute -> CREATE INSTANCE, I only see CPUs and no GPUs, as shown in the video below. I did select a region+zone that is supposed to have GPUs according to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200918045137/https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus)):

[image]

I see that some VMs from the marketplace comes with GPUs but I'd prefer to configure the VM myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the Deep Learning VM

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so one must go through the marketplace to get GPUs?

Comment: Unfortunately I think so, I have no idea why they do not include the option to select GPU's when making the default VM instance.

Comment: Got it, weird indeed.

Comment: Follow-up question: [Unable to SSH/gcloud into default Google Deep Learning VM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63970101/395857)

Answer (score 0):

You can get GPUs by selecting `N1` VM instance type:

[image]